# Max score_mode in nested score function is averaging instead

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

Goal: Return stores ranked by 2 factors (A: a gauss decay function which scores a store on it's distance from a lat long. B: Multiply (A:) by 1 or 100; 1 if none of the store's specials match a criteria, 100 if one (or more) of the store's specials match a criteria.

Example:

say I have stores described by this sudo-data;

```
Steve's store
  -Special (does not match criteria)
  -Special (does not match criteria)
  -Special (does match criteria)
-Location (somewhere near the given lat long)


Bob's store
  -Special (does not match criteria)
  -Special (does not match criteria)
-Location (somewhere near the given lat long)

Sally's store
  -Special (does match criteria)
  -Special (does match criteria)
  -Special (does match criteria)
-Location (somewhere far away from the given lat long)
```

Then, steve's store should have a score of something like 89.2933, Bob's store should have a score of something like 89.23223, Sally's should have a score like 12.1

Mapping:

```
{
"store": {
"properties": {
  "explain": {
    "type": "boolean"
  },
  "specials": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "end_date": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "store_id": {
        "analyzer": "lowercase_keyword",
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "image_url": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "details": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "id": {
        "analyzer": "lowercase_keyword",
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "fine_print": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "order": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "start_date": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  },
  "city": {
    "type": "keyword"
  },
  "logo_image_url": {
    "type": "keyword"
  },
  "cover_image_url": {
    "type": "keyword"
  },
  "number_of_reviews": {
    "type": "integer"
  },
  "tag_line": {
    "type": "keyword"
  },
  "address2": {
    "type": "keyword"
  },
  "address1": {
    "type": "keyword"
  },
  "phone": {
    "type": "keyword"
  }… and so on.
```

Query:

```
POST stores/store/_search
{ 
  "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "functions": [
            {
              "gauss": {
                "location": {
                  "scale": "8mi",
                  "origin": "47.1338379197262,-122.266475055481",
                  "decay": 0.5
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "specials",
                    "query": {
                      "function_score": {
                        "query": {
                          "bool": {
                            "must_not": [
                              {
                                "range": {
                                  "specials.start_date": {
                                    "gt": "now"
                                  }
                                }
                              },
                              {
                                "range": {
                                  "specials.end_date": {
                                    "lt": "now"
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        "boost_mode": "replace",
                        "score_mode": "max", 
                        "functions": [
                          {
                            "script_score": {

                              "script": {
                                "lang": "painless",
                                "inline": "<my_script>"
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Resulting explain json (relevant part):

```
 …{
     "value": 12,
     "description": "Score based on 9 child docs in range from 24064 to 24072, best match:",
    "details": [
        {
         "value": 100,
         "description": "sum of:",
         "details": [
              {
               "value": 100,
               "description": "min of:",
               "details": [
                   {
                    "value": 100,
                    "description": "script score function, computed with script:\"<my_script>" and parameters: \n{}",
                     "details": [
                                {
                                  "value": 0,
                                  "description": "_score: ",
                                  "details": [
                                    {
                                      "value": 0,
                                      "description": "sum of:",
                                      "details": [
                                        {
                                          "value": 0,
                                          "description": "match on required clause, product of:",
                                          "details": [
                                            {
                                              "value": 0,
                                              "description": "# clause",
                                              "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                              "value": 1,
                                              "description": "*:*, product of:",
                                              "details": [
                                                {
                                                  "value": 1,
                                                  "description": "boost",
                                                  "details": []
                                                },
                                                {
                                                  "value": 1,
                                                  "description": "queryNorm",
                                                  "details": []
                                                }
                                              ]
                                            }
                                          ]
                                        }
                                      ]
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 3.4028235e+38,
                              "description": "maxBoost",
                              "details": []
                            }
                          ]
                          …
```

My Script:
    100 if some criteria is met in a "special", 1 otherwise.

Result:

The score for that script function is 12 (because the store has 9 specials, only one of which matches the score script's criteria)— so that 12 is coming from (100+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)/9=12. That is multiplied by the score for the gauss distance decay function (0.36248797) to equal `4.7596407`. In other words, the script score ends up being an average of all the store's specials.

Expected:

I'd expect/desire for the script functions score to score the store by taking the max from the script score function applied to each special of a store. So in the above example, because the store has 1 special that matches the script's condition, that special should be scored 100. That 100 is the max of all scores for all specials in that store, since the other 8 that don't match the criteria. So that 100 should be multiplied by the gauss decay function to result in 0.36248797 * 100 = 36.248797

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Many, many thanks!

Comment: also please share a sample json source document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think (based on the stripped-down/reduced information you provided) that you are doing something wrong.

The [`nested` query also has a `score_mode`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) and this one is used to combine the scores of the children. What you did in your query is to combine the scores of the root documents (the parents of the children). But the matching children scores is combined using the `nested` query's `score_mode`. The nested `score_mode`'s default is `avg`. You should change that to `max` and try again.

So your query I think it should be:

```
{ 
  "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "functions": [
            {
              "gauss": {
                "location": {
                  "scale": "8mi",
                  "origin": "47.1338379197262,-122.266475055481",
                  "decay": 0.5
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "specials",
                    "score_mode": "max",
                    "query": {
                      "function_score": {
                      ...........
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct my friend! Thanks a million!!